# Test running issues

Tags: apex, apextestrunresult

Tried running the test for the first time and seems I am doing something wrong can someone give me a hint? I saved it before running the code but the star never disappeared

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please avoid posting code as screenshots, as it makes it harder to work with (we can't copypaste the text, and screen readers can't assist those that need assistance). You can [edit] your question to include code using the `{}` editor button for formatting. Also, please read about [ask] and take our quick [tour].

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors at the bottom of your screen. They both state that there is a missing method or incorrect signature. For example, if your TestHelper class has this method:

```
public static void yourName(String name) {
  // ... some logic
}
```

Then writing this:

```
System.assert(TestHelper.yourName('Ardasher Bobojonov', myName));
```

Would be invalid, because you're providing *two* parameters, but Apex expected only *one*.

The `*` never went away, because Salesforce refuses to save code that's in an invalid state. You'll have to look at `TestHelper` to determine the correct method name, the number and data type of all parameters, etc. Also, make sure that TestHelper has actually been saved in your org as well. You can use the File > Open/Open Resource dialogs to find these files. If the class isn't there, you'll have to deploy it somehow.